# Integrating Different Xcode projects into a single project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4

In my iphone app, I had initially divided the app into modules.

Each module was prepared as an individual xcode project.

Now I have integrated all modules by referencing and copying necessary files.

I want to submit it to the app store.

Will Apple accept this project which is comprised of different individual modules being referenced into one?

Is this is the right way of doing it?

Is there any better way?

Should I consider recreating the whole project into one?

Would different App delegates not be an issue if we do so?

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to Xcode's ability to make cross-project references?  Turning it into a single project sounds like a world of pain, and I don't see why having cross-project references should be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit it to the app store you submit a single .app binary and not an xcode project. Apple won't even know you're referencing other projects. It will just build all the files you need and compile it into the single binary.